# How to call from code onProgressChanged for SeekBar?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to call from code onProgressChanged for SeekBar ?  Is there similiar stuff like perform click for button ?

Comment: you mean like 1%..2%........100% like that ?

Comment: Does it still unresolved?

Answer (score 3):

Use this listener on seek bar object

```
        SeekBar seek=new SeekBar(this);
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
        // Here call your code when progress will changes
        }
     });
```